# Invert regular expression match in TextMate

Tags: regex, textmate

I have this string:

```
goose goose goose random goose goose test goose goose goose
```

I'm using regular expression in TextMate to find any word that isn't `goose`. therefore `random` and `test`.

So I tried this regular expression:

```
[^\sgoose\s]
```

But this isn't quite doing what I want. It's matching any character that isn't a `space` or letters `g` `o` `s` `e`.

How can I find get the regular expression to match any whole word that isn't `goose`? Therefore, there should be 2 matches `random` and `test`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure it will work with TextMate (I do not have it, but I've tested with Notepad++).

You could try:

```
\b(?:(?!goose)\w)+\b
```

**Explanation:**

```
\b          : word boundary
(?:         : start non capture group
  (?!goose) : negative lookahead, make sure we don't have the word "goose"
  \w        : a word character, you may use "[a-zA-Z]" for letters only or "." for any character but newline
)+          : group may appears 1 or more times
\b          : word boundary
```

Answer (score 1):

I find mistake in this expression, you can check it here: https://regex101.com/r/XQhqAB/1

As you see, the previous expression `\b(?:(?!goose)\w)+\b` doesn't find: `gooses1`, `goose1` and all the words that start from the `goose` prefix. Obviously these are other words...

Correct expression (for extended words): `(?<=^|\s)(?!goose(?:\s|$))\S+(?=\s|$)`
You test it here: https://regex101.com/r/XQhqAB/4

Correct expression (for simple words): `\b(?!goose\b)\w+\b`
Test it: https://regex101.com/r/XQhqAB/5

Sincerely.

Comment: (1) OK, good job; your expression finds words that begin with “goose”; for example, “gooseberry” and “goosepimple”.  (2) Your regex also matches words that end with “goose”; for example, “mongoose” and “wildgoose”. But shame on you for not noticing that [the other answer](https://superuser.com/q/1334062/354511#1334072) fails on those, too.  (3) The OP accepted Toto’s answer, which uses ``\b``, suggesting that that met their needs. So why did you replace it with `\s` alternations? Your answer does not catch non-goose words if they are adjacent to punctuation.

Comment: Thank you, and I think you're right. The expression can be simplified and optimized: `\b(?!goose\b)\w+\b`.